# Byte to integer

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a byte to integer.  All the searches I have done use byte[] which I assume is any array. I want to convert F byte (not b as show below)  but it gives error to change: not applicable to the argument.

```
    byte F;
    mmInStream.read(packetBytes);            

    b [counter]= packetBytes[0];             
    F=b [counter];
    counter++;
    temp = byteToInt(b); //Convert byte to int
```

Here is a byte To Int I found on one of the sites.

```
    private int byteToInt(byte[] b) {

        int value= 0;
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){                
        int n=(b[i]<0?(int)b[i]+256:(int)b[i])<<(8*i);             
    value+=n;
   }         
   return value; 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```
byte b = ...;
int signedInt = b; // For negative bytes, resulting in negative ints
int unsignedInt = 0xFF & b; // For negative bytes, resulting in positive ints
```

FYI: An `int` is 4 bytes. So, that is the reason why the methods you found on the internet are using an array of bytes. They assume you pass an array of 4 bytes, which will be stitched together to make an int.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
int i = 234;
byte b = (byte) i;
System.out.println(b); // -22
int i2 = b & 0xFF;
System.out.println(i2); // 234
```

or this one also:

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a)
{
byte[] ret = new byte[4];
ret[3] = (byte) (a & 0xFF);   
ret[2] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);   
ret[1] = (byte) ((a >> 16) & 0xFF);   
ret[0] = (byte) ((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
return ret;
}
```

and

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b)
{
return (b[3] & 0xFF) + ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8) + ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((b[0] & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if b is unsigned

```
int i = b & 0xff;
```